# How was charge controlled for early experiments?

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, charge, coulombs-law

One of the first topics usually taught in electrostatics is Coulomb's law.  I understand that he measured the relationship between charge and distance using a torsion balance.  My question is, how was charge generated back then?  What kind of apparatus was used?  And how was it controlled?

Comment: The charge might be generated via electrostatic methods and then stored in [leyden jar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyden_jar) for use in future.

Comment: Duplicate - [How did Coulomb measure charges?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/468169/104696)

Comment: @Farcher at least the first part of the question isn't duplicate.